# JITWatch Metadata not found

Tags: java, jit

I'm generating logs in InteliJ Idea using vm parameters
`-XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+LogCompilation -Xlog:class+load=info`.

When I try to open compilation log in JITWatch it doesnt show my packages/classes instead I see  thosands of errors like "Metamember not found" and "Could not parse types" for my classes and jdk classes to.

What am I doing wrong? I tried with java 11 and 17 with no success.

Comment: I can not reproduce your problem. But as a side note, I wouldn’t mix unified logging options with legacy options. After all, the point of unified logging is, well, to be unified. You can use, e.g. just the single JVM option `-Xlog:class+load=info,jit+compilation=debug`

Comment: @holger When running code in sandbox there are no errors and I can see logs. Maybe it has something to do with external libraries like apache poi that my code is using? Should  I set those classes in configuration so jitwatch can find them?